# Postgres column casting

Tags: postgresql

I have a query

```
SELECT assetid, type_code, version, name, short_name, status, languages,
charset, force_secure, created, created_userid, updated, updated_userid,
published, published_userid, status_changed, status_changed_userid
FROM sq_ast WHERE assetid = 7
```

which doesn't work and throws

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 4: FROM sq_ast WHERE assetid = 7
```

I can get it to work by doing

```
SELECT assetid, type_code, version, name, short_name, status, languages,
charset, force_secure, created, created_userid, updated, updated_userid,
published, published_userid, status_changed, status_changed_userid
FROM sq_ast WHERE assetid = '7'
```

Please note the quoting of the 7 in the WHERE clause...

I am deploying an huge application and I cannot rewrite the core... similarly I don't want to risk changing the type of the column...

I'm no Postgres expert... please help...

Is there an option for strict casting of columns???

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version? a quick test suggests that 8.4 allows this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgresql is more strongly typed in recent versions, and that's a good thing. If `assetid` is VARCHAR, then you can't compare it to an integer (since 8.4, I believe).

In general (not only in Postgresql, not only in database design) it's bad design to mix those types: numeric datatypes should be used for real numeric fields, and not for strings that just happen to consist of digits.

For example, an invoice "number", or a credit card "number", should not normally be represented as "number", but as a string.

Sometimes, however, the decision is not clear (eg: document numbers).

Some criteria that can help:

- Are you potentially interested in doing **arithmetic** with your values (sum, substract)? Would that at least make sense? Then, it's an [number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html).
- Should **zeroes on the left** be preserved, or considered relevant? (is '07' to be regarded as different from '7'?) Then, it is a [string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html).

Depending on how you anwser these questions in your scenario (Is there an assetid that begins with 0? Could there be some non numeric character? Does it seem to be an serial number ?), you might consider to change the field type or (more probable in your scenario) to do a cast, in the prefered direction:

```
   SELECT... FROM sq_ast WHERE assetid::integer = 7
```

(if you decide that the field  is numeric) or elsewhere

```
   SELECT... FROM sq_ast WHERE assetid = '7'
```

There's no global setting for reverting to the old behaviour, and force an implicit cast for character types, AFAIK.

Comment: "There's no global setting for reverting to the old behaviour" - found on [another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18129968/243245), you can create implicit cast functions to mimic the old behaviour e.g. using the [script on the PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Image:Pg83-implicit-casts.sql).